# Poisson counting process question, but correct answer not obtained by usual method

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-distribution

Ok here's the question:

> Fisherman Dan is out fishing by a stream. On average, 3 fishes per
>   hour swim by but Fisherman Dan catches the fish with probability 1/2.
>   It rains in average once per day. The fish and the rain arrive
>   according to independent Poisson processes.
>
> Given that fisherman Dan caught exactly 2 fishes between 8 and 12
>   o'clock, what is the probability that he caught zero fish during the
>   first hour of fishing?

This was my initial solution:

\begin{align*}
& Pr(\text{2 fish caught during 8-12 o'clock | no fish caught during 8-9 o'clock}) = \\
= &Pr(N(12)\; - \;N(8)\; = 2\;|\; N(9)\;-\;N(8) = 0  \;) =\\
= &Pr(N(4)\; = 2\;|\; N(1) = 0  \;) =  \\
= & Pr(N(4)\; = 2\;)\cdot Pr(\; N(1) = 0  \;) =  \\
= & e^{-6}\dfrac{6^2}{2!} \cdot e^{-3/2} = \\
= &0.00995
\end{align*}

But in the answer sheet they've reasoned in this way instead (translated so keep that in mind):

> If the only thing we know is the number of events under a certain time
>   intervall and these events stem from a Poisson process, then we also
>   know that these events are independent and identically distributed
>   over the time intervall. Given two events occurred during 4 hours we
>   obtain:
>
> Pr(no event during the first hour) = Pr(both events during the
>   last three hours) = $(\dfrac{3}{4-0})^2 = \dfrac{9}{16} = 0.5625$

why doesn't my method work though? I understand their solution, but mine should work, right?

Comment: The probability of the wrong event was computed incorrectly. The first solution multiplies the probability of $2$ fish in $4$ hours by the probability of no fish in the first hour. If the events were independent, which they are not, ths would give us the probability of $2$ fish in $4$ hours **and** $0$ fish in one hour. But the problem asks us to compute a conditional probability, which is something else entirely.

Comment: yeah I could see why the two events are not independent. Thus it doesn't satisfy the increments ---> not a poisson counting process?

Comment: I would suggest going back to fundamentals, and writing out a solution as follows. Let $A$ be the event no fish in first hour, and let $B$ be the event $2$ fish in $4$ hours. We want $\Pr(A| B)$, which is $\Pr(A\cap B)/\Pr(B)$. The calcuation of $\Pr(B)$ is easy. For $\Pr(A\cap B)$, this is the probability of no fish in first hour times the probability of $2$ fish in the next **three** hours.

Answer (score 0):

You computed P(2 fish 8-12 | 0 fish 8-9) and you needed P(0 fish 8-9 | 2 fish 8-12)

Comment: well, by stationary and independent increments, it would be the same calculation.

Comment: $P(A|B) \neq P(B|A)$, even here

Comment: fair enough, but calculating P(0 fish 8-9 | 2 fish 8-12) instead, I would still use the increments to reach a solution. So what do I need to do instead?

Comment: and I conditioned the way I did because I figured why would you condition on the end-result, to find out the probability of what could have happened during a period in the time interval?

Comment: @DOGOFWALLSTREET because knowing what happened over a large interval influences information you know about its subintervals.